# Cannot access state in re-base syncState, after authentication with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a React app with the following shallow database model, hooked up to Firebase:

```
{
  "users": {
    "userid1": {
      "Full name": "Patrick Bateman",
    },
  },
  "posts": {
    "userid1": {
      "post-1": {
        text: "Lorem ipsum",
        ...
      },
      "post-2": {
        text: "Cats sure are swell",
        ...
      },
    },
    "userid2": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

and in React, I'm using the [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) library's `syncState()` to fetch initial content and keep the local state and firebase in sync.
In the re-base docs and examples, they use `syncState()` in `componentDidMount`. This makes sense, but I don't want to sync all the firebase posts; only those belonging to the user, so my instinct was to do something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs = base.syncState(`posts/${this.state.uid}`, {
    context: this,
    state: 'posts',
  });
}
```

The problem here is that `this.state.uid` is `null` at this stage in the lifecycle.

**My question is this: how do I access the uid when I call syncState?**

Here is the rest of my code for reference, show auth too:

```
init() {
  // I need the uid here!!!!!! 
  console.log(this.state.uid); // null
  this.refs = base.syncState(`posts/${this.state.uid}`, {
    context: this,
    state: 'posts',
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(storageKey, user.uid);
      this.setState({
        uid: user.uid,
        user
      });
    } else {
      window.localStorage.removeItem(storageKey);
      this.setState({
        uid: null,
        user: null,
        posts: null,
      });
    }
  });

  // re-base firebase sync
  this.init();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  base.removeBinding(this.ref);
  this.unsubscribe();
}

authenticate = (provider) => {
  if (provider === 'twitter') {
    provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
  } else if (provider === 'google') {
    provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
  }

  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((authData) => {
    // get the of the firebase.User instance
    const user = authData.user;
    // Set local storage to preserve login
    window.localStorage.setItem(storageKey, user.uid);
    // Set the state of the current user
    this.setState({
      uid: user.uid,
      user,
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

With the above code, my app creates local state correctly:

```
State
  posts: {
    post-1: {
      ...
    }
  }
```

but then on firebase, predicately adds them with a `null` user, since the uid is not available.

```
database: {
  posts: {
    null: {
      post-1: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `this.init()` after the state sets. `this.setState` has a second argument that is a callback. This way you can be sure that the `uid` will not be null.

**Example**

```
this.setState({
  uid: user.uid,
  user
}, () => {
  this.init();
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!